# How to submit values to list using infopath 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, infopath

I have a list named "**list1**". Data to "List1" are submitted using List InfoPath forms. In my list Infopath forms of "List1", data for the controls are coming from "List1" and my requirement is, the data from the List InfoPath forms has to be submitted to "List2".

"List1" and "List2" has same number and type of columns.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't entirely clear to me what you really want to do, however, if I understand it correctly, instead of attaching your InfoPath form to List1, you can do the opposite, that is attach it to List2. Then, you add a new data connection to retrieve the data you need from List1, use it to eg. populate the form fields and then send it to List2.